# Navigation Pipeline Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I followed the [Aurelia documentation](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/doc/article/securing-your-app) about adding a Navigation Pipeline step.

I've created my Auth service and AuthRouterPipelineStep:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import 'fetch';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
import {AuthResult} from './authResult';
import {Redirect} from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(HttpClient, Router)
export class Auth {
    constructor(httpClient, router) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
        this.router = router;
        this.internalIsLoggedIn = false;
    }

    login(username, password) {

        if (username === "callum" && password === "password") {
            this.router.navigate('products');

            this.internalIsLoggedIn = true;
        }

        return new AuthResult("Unable to login.");
    }

    get isLoggedIn() { return this.internalIsLoggedIn; }
}

@inject(Auth)
export class AuthRouterPipelineStep {
    constructor(auth) {
        this.auth = auth;
    }

    run(navigationInstruction, next) {
        console.log("Navigating");
        if (navigationInstruction
                .getAllInstructions()
                .some(i => i.config.settings.roles.indexOf('public') === -1)) 
        {
            var isLoggedIn = this.auth.isLoggedIn;
            if (!isLoggedIn) {
                return next.cancel(new Redirect('welcome'));
            }
        }

        return next();
    }
}
```

And in my App I've configure it all:

```
import {Auth, AuthRouterPipelineStep} from './auth/auth';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Redirect} from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Auth)
export class App {
    constructor(auth) {
        this.auth = auth;
    }

    get isLoggedIn() { return this.auth.isLoggedIn; }

    configureRouter(config, router) {
        config.title = 'Reaper';
        config.addPipelineStep('authorise', AuthRouterPipelineStep);
        config.map([
            { route: ['', 'welcome'], name: 'welcome',      moduleId: 'welcome',           nav: true, title: 'Home',      settings: { icon: 'fa-home', roles: ['public'] } },
            { route: 'contacts',      name: 'contacts',     moduleId: './contacts/index',  nav: true, title: 'Contacts',  settings: { icon: 'fa-' } },
            { route: 'companies',     name: 'companies',    moduleId: './companies/index', nav: true, title: 'Companies', settings: { icon: 'fa-' } },
            { route: 'products',      name: 'products',     moduleId: './products/index',  nav: true, title: 'Products',  settings: { icon: 'fa-' } }
        ]);

        this.router = router;
    }
}
```

I have a `console.log` on the Navigation Pipeline step `Run` function. That never gets called. What have I missed...?

I do know that all navigation steps are injected by the container, so you can have dependencies in the constructor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as of Aurelia Beta 1. There are several hooks in the Navigation Pipeline. One being `authorize` and the other being `modelbind`.

So the name of pipeline step to add is very important. `Authorise` in my code is wrong, that is why the "middleware" isn't getting picked up.

You can however stack up middleware and it will run sequentially:

```
config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthRouterPipelineStep);
config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AnotherAuthRouterPipelineStep);
```